# How to perform randomized pairing/matching in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, google-sheets, automation

I have a list of names that I'd like to split into two groups where one person should not be matched with another person more than once until the person has been matched with every other person in the list. For example,in a list such as this one -

Glen,
John,
Mark,
Shane,
Ricky,
Steve

This group of 6 should be divided into 2 groups and Glen should be mapped with every other person without repetitive matching.

Here's what I tried

```
import random
name_list = ['Glen','John','Mark','Shane','Ricky','Steve']
random.shuffle(name_list)
T1 = pd.Series(name_list[:(len(name_list)/2)])
T2 = pd.Series(name_list[(len(name_list)/2):]
```

But I see some repeated matching with this method. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

(edit)
**Expected output**

**First iteration:**
| T1 | T2 |
| -------- | -------------- |
| Glen    | Shane            |
| John   | Ricky            |
| Mark   | Steve          |

**Second iteration:**
| T1 | T2 |
| -------- | -------------- |
| Steve    | Mark            |
| John   | Shane            |
| Ricky   | Glen          |

**Third iteration:**
| T1 | T2 |
| -------- | -------------- |
| Steve    | Shane            |
| Glen   | Mark            |
| John   | Glen          |

Check here for ref: [Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSRXv.png)

See how Glen is mapped to different person in each iteration (so is the case for every other name in the list). Basically, everyone should be paired with everyone else until the list gets exhausted.

Comment: Could you add an output that you except for your question?

Comment: Hey, just added

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

```py
name_list = ['Glen','John','Mark','Shane','Ricky','Steve']
partition = len(name_list) // 2
part1, part2 = np.array_split(name_list, 2)
idx = np.arange(partition)
np.random.shuffle(idx)
roll = np.arange(partition)
np.random.shuffle(roll)
for i in roll:
    roll_idx = np.roll(idx, i)
    print(np.vstack([part1, part2[:partition][roll_idx]]).T)
```

### Output

```
[['Glen' 'Ricky']
 ['John' 'Shane']
 ['Mark' 'Steve']]
[['Glen' 'Steve']
 ['John' 'Ricky']
 ['Mark' 'Shane']]
[['Glen' 'Shane']
 ['John' 'Steve']
 ['Mark' 'Ricky']]
```

### Explanation

- Using the shuffled `index` for `np.ndarray` object will return the value of the corresponding.
- `part2[:partition][idx]` can make sure that their length of them are equal.

Comment: Wonderful suggestion, thank you! However, do you think everyone in the list is mapped to another person? In the output you shared, Glen is mapped with Steve, Shane, Ricky but I was expecting him to get mapped to all the persons in the list.

Comment: @BharathM as you can see, I invoke the `np.roll` method, the second arg is the distance you want to shift. So I can be sure that each name from part1 can match part1 for only once

Comment: @BharathM but, btw, if you want to generate `[AD, BE, CF]` and `[AD, BF, CE]` as two different pairings from `[A, B, C, D, E, F]`. Then that will be another question. Here I just use the capital letter to represent the name.

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions! Simply put, I wanted one person to be paired with every other person in the list in each iteration. The group that gets divided will be random each time.

Comment: @BharathM then my code can meet your needs.